# Spotfire: Flag Change Over Multiple Columns

Tags: spotfire

Trying to create a flag column if there is any change in my data set. Here is what the original data looks like:

[image]

If there is change in the employee name from the last report, I would like to flag it (See in Feb, Randall drops off, Dec is the first report in the list). I have many report dates and crews, the example here just shows 1. Not sure if this is possible, I am newer to Spotfire so I appreciate any/all help. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would like to flag this event? I.e. what should the flag column contain? From what I see in this example, the 'Desired:C' column is the flag and you want the number of employees that are no longer there? But what if a new employee joins?

Comment: I've been tasked with anytime a crew changes (so in this case crew 5), so I'm looking for a name change from the last report, if that makes sense. If an employee drops off or is added, then I want to flag it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
if you want it all in one calculated column

```
case  when Last(UniqueConcatenate([Employee Name]) over ([Crew Number],[Report 
Date])) over (Intersect(Previous([Report Date]),[Crew 
Number]))!=UniqueConcatenate([Employee Name]) over ([Crew Number],[Report Date]) 
then 1 else 0 end
```

If you prefer to use an intermediate column, for clarity:

define [tmp] as:

```
UniqueConcatenate([Employee Name]) over ([Crew Number],[Report Date])
```

then:

```
case  when Last([tmp]) over (Intersect(Previous([Report Date]),[Crew Number]))!= 
[tmp] then 1 else 0 end
```

However you may have a lot of people in your crews.